# Page width exceeds the 100% of the screen width

Tags: jquery, html, css, tags, width

I have a strange problem, I was designing a page and after I finished, found that there is a horizontal scroll bar in the bottom of the page, I checked the page html but found that there is a close tag for each tag.

Also I tried to check the widths using jQuery and found that 
$(window).width()      =   1351px
and 
$(document).width()    =   1480px

any suggestions about what reason for this problem ?

Comment: Can we see the page?

Comment: What is your screen resolution?

Comment: You have some "block" element wider than your screen width.

Comment: till now, the page is offline, just on my pc, I will upload it soon

Comment: my screen resolution is 1366 x 768

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the your web inspector go through and delete interior elements until the scroll bar goes away. Then fix the width for that element (float:left may work). Probably what is happening is there is an element which is too wide for the page. It is not breaking anything, it is just causing the scroll bar.

Comment: Thanks Scott, I did it using this way, it is a hard way, but it worked, it was a div that has is not assigned a width but it has a <ul> that has width.

Comment: @AmirIskander I find a more expedient way to do this is to set your stylesheet to an empty css file and then just adjust the width in dev tools until you see what is not responding to changes in width and thus clipping past viewport.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do it I found is by

```
* {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This may be an easy quick fix, but not advised. Instead, doing `* {outline: 1px solid red;}` will highlight the issue, and it can be addressed directly.

Answer (score 0):

This issue came for me , I have searched through the complete page and there is a div whose width is in 10000 because of that the page is showing a horizontal bar i have changed it to 100% and the issue is fixed i wonder why that is issue is only coming for me in the chrome and edge and not coming in firefox

Please comment down below if the issue for you is only coming in chrome and not in firefox.

Code after fix is

```
<div id="ext-comp-1025" style="height: auto; width: 100%;"
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't track any offending items and no horizontal scroll appearing. Driving me nuts.

Solution for me

```
max-width: -webkit-fill-available;
```