# HTML document width exceeds 100% when i increase the height to bigger than screen height

Tags: html, css, web

Everything looked fine (width is 100% of screen) until i increased the height of the page to bigger than the screen's height. After that the width increased to 1925pixels, even though the screen resolution is 1920px [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftw8B.jpg). Please help, im not copying code right now ,because the problem could be anywhere

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,100italic,300italic,300,400italic,500,500italic,700&subset=latin,latin  -ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body style="background-color: #f3f3f3; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
    <div id="topbar_bg">
        <div id="topbar_content">
            <img src="C:\Users\User\Dropbox\+HOROS code\img\logo.png"; style="margin-top: 18px">
            <ul id="menu">
            <li>PASLAUGOS</li>
            <li>APIE MUS</li>
            <li>DRAUGAI</li>
            <li>BLOGAS</li>
            <li>KONTAKTAI</li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="social">
            <li><img src="C:\Users\User\Dropbox\+HOROS code\img\fb.png"></li>
            <li><img src="C:\Users\User\Dropbox\+HOROS code\img\twitter.png"></li>
            <li><img src="C:\Users\User\Dropbox\+HOROS code\img\g+.png"></li>
            <li><img src="C:\Users\User\Dropbox\+HOROS code\img\yt.png"></li>
            </ul>
            <Div style="position: relative; margin-top: -70px;">
            <ul id="kalbos"><li style="color: #ecb315">LT</li><li>EN</li>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Pradinis">
        <img src="C:\Users\User\Dropbox\+HOROS code\img\akvedukas.png" style="box-shadow: 0px 1px #dcdcdc; margin-top: -7px;">
        <div id="PradinisContent">
            <div id="slogan">
                <p>From Possibility <br /> to Reality</p>
            </div>
            <div id="intro">
                <h1>HOROS</h1>
                <p>Human Resources Solutions</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Paslaugos">
        <div id="paslaugosContent">
            <p class="Pavadinimas">HOROS siūlo šias paslaugas:</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

http://pastebin.com/UxCrT4MR

Comment: What about posting some actual code for people to look at? Like you say, problem could be anywhere. Give us something to work with.

Comment: If you can post your code then we batter help you..

Comment: That's because of your CSS and a scroll bar. You've done something wrong, and to tell what exactly we need to see your CSS.

Comment: added the css and html codes

Comment: I had same problem. Check this link, it might helps you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12009440/1310540

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Page width exceeds the 100% of the screen width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009315/page-width-exceeds-the-100-of-the-screen-width)

Answer (score 1):

Scroll bar is causing the display area to be smaller than the actual page size.

It would be great to see your code, it would certainly let more people help you know how you have implemented it.

My guess would be that you need to remove your fixed pixel width of 1920px and set it as 100%, or something more desktop screen friendly like 960px.

Comment: Everywhere width is set 100% though, if you could check my code that would be great

Answer (score 0):

When you increase height, a vertical scroll bar appears in order to let you view the entire page. As your width is also 100%, an horizontal scroll bar appears too, in order to compensate the width of the vertical scroll bar.

Comment: I added the code, can you check it out what i could change to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Make the width responsive and not fixed with

> @media